# Canvas.putImageDate - Weird Behaviour

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, putimagedata

I'm trying to use perlin noise to create a noise map using html canvas.

Here's my code:

```
            const width = noiseMap.length
            const height = noiseMap[0].length
            const colorMap = new Array(width * height).fill(0)
            
            const canvas = canvasRef.current
            const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
            
            const imageData = ctx.createImageData(width, height)

            for (let y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                for (let x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                    const index = y * width + x
                    const pixelIndex = index * 4

                    const rgbaColor: rgbaColorType = hexRgb(lerp('#FFFFFF', '#000000', noiseMap[x][y]))
                    colorMap[index] = rgbaColor

                    imageData.data[pixelIndex] = rgbaColor.red
                    imageData.data[pixelIndex + 1] = rgbaColor.green
                    imageData.data[pixelIndex + 2] = rgbaColor.blue
                    imageData.data[pixelIndex + 3] = rgbaColor.alpha
                }
            }

            console.log(imageData)
            ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0)
```

Contextual Information:

**noiseMap** is a bidimensional array that contains numbers from 0 to 1 (floatish). The noise map array sizes are equal to the canvas width / height.

Once I run this code, the canvas doesn't get painted at all.
Curiously, if I remove index multiplication from:

```
const pixelIndex = index * 4
```

to

```
const pixelIndex = index
```

It renders this:

[image]
Note that noise map get clamped, because I'm not properly assigning data to imageData.data. In fact, about 3/4 of the imageData.data array receives 0.

So I definitely need to multiply the pixelIndex by 4. Which based on console log properly populate my imageData.data array.

So I'm wondering what may be happening.... any clues?

Comment: did you check how much of the data in `noiseMap` is `0` or `NaN`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes I did, some are naturally zero, but nowhere close close to 3/4 of the dataArray.

Comment: I think the initialization of `width` and `height` is wrong as in a two-dimensional array the length equals the rows (so try `const width = noiseMap[0].length;const height = noiseMap.length;`) I can't say that this will cause the error though so you might also post a reproducible code sample that clearly shows the issue you're having.

Comment: @ThiagoFacchini it's sufficient if enough of them land on the alpha-channel. But I think obscure's drift might be more likely to cause the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the replies,

Currently my map dimensions are 600w | 800h.

Console.log results are:
width: 600
height: 800

ImgDataArray.data array size was 1920000 which make sense
600w*800h * 4 rgba values.

@obscure, I tried but then I get errors with the array indexes.... The initialization doesn't seem to be the case....

On regards of reproducible code, it's pretty much it. the noiseMap is a bidemensional array containing number from 0 to 1.

My guess it's something with imageData or putImageData itself....

Tried quite a lot so far.... :(

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone who tried to help.

The issue was quite simple, the line:

```
pixelIndex = index * 4
```

was the cause, it would blow the imagedata.data array by one position, so the solution was quite simple:

```
pixelIndex = (index * 4) -1
```

Done.